# How to show that the sequence $a^{\frac1{2n-1}}$ converges to $-1$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If  $a$ belongs to the interval $(-1,0)$, how do I prove that the sequence $a^{\frac1{(2n-1)}}$ converges to $-1$?

Comment: It doesn't.  As you have written it, it converges to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edit you can see that $a^{1/(2n-1)}=-b^{1/(2n-1)}$ where $b=-a\in(0,1)$ and clearly $b^{1/(2n-1)}\to b^0=1$.

Comment: Absolutely, given the final edit.